# Populating HABTM relation when using where on said relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Let's say I have a post model which has and belongs to many categories. When I pull a list of posts for a certain category (with id = 1) I do it like this:

`posts = Post.includes(:categories).where(categories: { id: 1 })`

Suppose the first post of this list belongs to 3 categories, however when I do:

`posts.first.categories`

... it only shows the category with id = 1.

Is there a way to populate all of the categories so that I don't have to do N + 1 when looping through the posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it this way

```
posts = Category.find(1).posts
```

Now you have all the posts in the category, with all categories for each post available.

Comment: `posts = Category.find(1).posts:includes(:categories)` does exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I can see that.  The eager loading gives you a performance improvement.